# Jive plugin implementation of Freemarker #list

Tags: freemarker

Newbie question here about the connection between FreeMarker templates and Jive plugins (written in Java).

I have inherited an existing, working project with some FTL, as follows:

```
<#list employeeInstances! as instance>
  <tr>
  ...
  </tr>
</#list>
```

I'm trying to understand how *employeeInstances* is actually implemented in the Java plugin.  There is no reference to 'employeeInstances' anywhere else within the project.  The closest is this:

```
public ArrayList<EmployeeInstance> getEmployeeInstances()
{
  ...
}
```

I am guessing that this is what's being called when Jive sees #list employeeInstances.  Is that right?  Is it basically capitalizing the first letter of the sequence name 'employeeInstances' and then prefixing it with the word 'get'?  I couldn't find anything in the FreeMarker or Jive documentation that discussed this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what data-model is passed to `Template.process` or `Environment.process`. If it's an instance of the class with the `getEmployeeInstances` method, then your guess was right. FreeMarker exposes JavaBean properties as variables, so `getFoo()` becomes to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks.  Even though I don't see any reference to ".process" within the project (FTL or JAVA source, or any other files for that matter) I guess it's just a bean interface thing.  I love how difficult it has become to connect the dots in software ever since OO arrived.

Comment: Certainly `process` is called in some of the dependency jar-s. Because somewhere it must be called. (Put a debugger break point on it and see who's the caller.)